# What's the difference between a CRC and a checksum?

Tags: networking

What's the difference between a CRC and a checksum?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[CRC (Cyclic Redundancy Check)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) is a type of [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum), specifically a *position dependent* checksum algorithm (among others, such as [Fletcher's checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum), [Adler-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32)). As their name suggest, these detect positional changes as well, which makes them more robust - thus more widely used - than other checksum methods.

Comment: CRC is not at all robust. Its positional nature does make it a decent integrity check, but you should use a cryptographic hash like MD5 if you can afford its higher computational cost. If computation isn't an issue, I recommend SHA256. See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49115040/519360).

Comment: CRCs were not designed to resist collisions, rather to catch transmission and other errors such as read errors.

Answer (score 17):

CRC refers to a specific checksum algorithm. Other types of checksums are XOR, modulus, and all the various cryptographic hashes.

Answer (score 13):

Check out [HowStuffWorks](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/encryption7.htm) for a good description of both and how they differ.

From the page:

Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC)

> CRCs are similar in concept to checksums, but they use polynomial division to determine the value of the CRC

More info is given at the link above including an example of how a checksum is calculated.

Answer (score 9):

Jeff Atwood (founder of Stack Overflow) wrote in his [Checksums and Hashes](https://blog.codinghorror.com/checksums-and-hashes/) blog post:

> I learned to appreciate the value of the Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC) algorithm in my 8-bit, 300 baud file transferring days. If the CRC of the local file matched the CRC stored in the file (or on the server), I had a valid download. I also learned a little bit about the [pigeonhole principle](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/pigeon.shtml) when I downloaded a file with a matching CRC that was corrupt!

A [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) is an [error detection scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction#Error_detection_schemes) that typically refers to a cryptographic hash function, though it also includes CRCs. Here are three different types of checksums:

**[Cyclic Redundancy Checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)** like [CRC-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#CRC-32_algorithm) are fast but collision-prone. They are not robust to [collision attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack); somebody could take a given CRC and easily create a second input that matches it.

**[Cryptographic hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)** like [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) (weaker), [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) (weak), and [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) (strong) are specifically designed to be resistant to collision attacks. They are preferable to CRCs in every situation except speed. Use the strongest algorithm you can computationally afford.

**[Key derivation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function)** like [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) and [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) generate secret keys, though they are better known for hashing passwords. This takes advantage of KDF [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) to make even shorter passwords more expensive to compute and therefore more robust to [brute-force attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack).

---

See also this [Crypto.SE question on CRC vs SHA1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26652/12618). Wikipedia has a [hash function security summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function_security_summary) page that discusses collision-proneness of various cryptographic hashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166264/discussion-between-adam-katz-and-zaph).

Comment: Checksums are not necessarily cryptographic hash functions, they can be as simple as as an arithmetic sum of the byte values. See [Modular Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum#Modular_sum) and more generally [Checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum). Perhaps you need to lead some security research WRT checksums.

Comment: @zaph – I've had that corrected for several revisions, and I also incorporated your other feedback as it came in. Modular Sum is indeed a checksum. XOR is not. As I noted in chat, I am still interested in your constructive feedback and would like to know how I could turn your -1 into a +1. Let's stop debating items that are already fixed in my answer.

Comment: If you disagree that "checksum" typically refers to a cryptographic checksum, especially when differentiating it from "CRC", then I understand your point. The whole point to my answer is that CRC only has specific uses and is not a good generic integrity checksum. LRC looks very interesting but it does not serve as a good illustration of a checksum that is substantially different from CRC.