# Compute checksum on file from command line

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, checksum

Looking for a command or set of commands that are readily available on Linux distributions that would allow me to create a script to generate a checksum for a file.

This checksum is generated by a build system I have no control over by summing every single byte in the file and then truncating that number to 4 bytes.

I know how to do do this using tools like node.js, perl, python, C/C++, etc, but I need to be able to do this on a bare bones Linux distribution running remotely that I can't modify (it's on a PLC).

Any ideas?  I've been searching for awhile and haven't found anything that looks straightforward yet.

Comment: `cksum` and `ssh` can be used in conjunction if they are available on the remote system.

Comment: cksum doesn't give me what I need, it's gives a CRC, I just need a byte by byte summation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357053/what-the-difference-between-crc-and-checksum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for byte by byte summation and truncating that number to 4 bytes using much primitive shell commands.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

declare -a bytes
bytes=(`xxd -p -c 1 INPUT_FILE | tr '\n' ' '`)

total=0;
for(( i=0; i<${#bytes[@]}; i++));
do
    total=$(($total + 0x${bytes[i]}))
    if [ $total > 4294967295 ]; then
            total=$(($total & 4294967295))
    fi
done

echo "Checksum: " $total
```

Comment: That did it!  But it's slow, took about 50 seconds for a 1.2 MB file.  I moved the if statement to outside the for loop, because it only really needs to run once at the end of the summation, and that cut it to 17 seconds.  Was actually pretty surprised how fast that made it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do byte by byte summation and truncating that number to 4 bytes then the following command can be used.

```
xxd -p -c 1 <Input file> | awk '{s+=$1; if(s > 4294967295) s = and(4294967295, s) } END {print s}'
```

The `xxd` command is used extract hexdump of the input file and each byte is added to compute the sum. If the sum exceeds `2^32-1 = 4294967295` value, then a bitwise and operation is performed to truncate the bits.

Comment: Here is the result I get when I run your command:  username@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ xxd -p -c 1 DEFAULT.PRG | awk '{s+=$1; if(s > 4294967295) s = and(4294967295, s) } END {print s}'
awk: line 2: function and never defined

Comment: Same result running it from within a script

Comment: I tried that command before posting here nd even the [tutorials point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_built_in_functions.htm) describes it. Could you please try using gawk instead of awk ?

Comment: Gawk wasn't installed on the system I need this to work on, but I did it on another system and it did run, but still isn't giving me the number I'm getting from the build system and from my custom node.js script that I can run on my main system, not on the PLC, I wonder if it's adding the numbers directly from xxd instead of taking into account that they are 2 byte hex numbers each taking 2 characters to express

Comment: xxd prints hex, but (at least my) awk won't parse the hex values to integers.  This command prints the bytes one per line in decimal instead of hex: od -t u1 -An -w1 -v

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried cksum? I use it inside a few scripts. It's very simple to use.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/cksum

Comment: I did try cksum but it's not giving me the result I need.  My understanding is that cksum does a CRC, but I don't need that I just need a byte summation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357053/what-the-difference-between-crc-and-checksum

Comment: Well, that is to say that is my understanding of cksum, I would love to find out I'm simply using it wrong and it can work for me

Comment: If you need another algorithm to do the work for you, maybe you can take a look on `md5sum` and `sha1sum` commands. In case you  want to exchange the files later (an ISO file for example), i'd suggest `md5sum`.